# Cannot insert character '≤' in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a SQL Server 2008 database and a `nvarchar(256)` field of a table. The crazy problem is that when I run this query:

```
update ruds_values_short_text 
set value = '≤ asjdklasd' 
where rud_id=12202 and field_code='detection_limit'
```

and then

```
select * from ruds_values_short_text  
where rud_id=12202 and field_code='detection_limit'
```

I get this result:

```
12202 detection_limit = asjdklasd 11
```

You can see that the character ≤ has been transformed in =

It's an encoding related problem, for sure, in fact, if I try to paste '≤' in Notepad++ it pastes '=' but I get '≤' when I convert ANSI to UTF-8.

So.. I think I should write the query in UTF8.. but how? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `N` prefix so the literal is treated as Unicode rather than being treated as character data in the code page of your database's default collation.

```
update ruds_values_short_text 
set value = N'≤ asjdklasd'
where rud_id=12202 and field_code='detection_limit'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `update ruds_values_short_text set value = N'≤ asjdklasd' where rud_id=12202 and field_code='detection_limit'`. The N indicates that you are providing national language so it respects the encoding.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer although I can't really call it mine anymore now can I :)